# Windows Forms Stuck During Program Execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have an application that reads data on the main form as well as a pop-up window. On my application's main form I am reading real-time serial communication in ASCII. In my pop-up window my program is analyzing that data and capturing pass/fail scenarios.

When I execute my program it works as intended. However, while the program is running (takes ~2 minutes to finish) I can't move my pop-up window around the screen or minimize my main application window. It's as if they're stuck until the operation is complete. I am not getting a "Not Responding" message and am trying to figure out how to be able move/minimize/close windows during the operation.

Is multi-threading the answer? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are blocking the UI. You should do this kind of work on a separate thread. Use `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Yes, the main thread is locked up so you want to go to using a background thread

Comment: Rough guess is that you are fire-hosing the UI thread by calling BeginInvoke() from your DataReceived event handler way too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably performing some very long opração the 'main thread'. Try to create a new 'thread' to run this very large operation, and your form will not be locked.

Comment: At a high level my program is reading serial data (main window), displaying serial data (main window), and analyzing the data (pop-up window). Everything is sequential since I need to receive a line of data and immediately analyze it. Would multithreading run these in parallel? If so I am not sure that would work since I need the sequential order.

Comment: You can try to create a manager, create a list and add itens to analyse, and your thread can analyse in order.

Comment: Do you recommend any tutorials on how to create a manager, list, etc.?

Comment: I do not know any tutorial, but it is very simple, just create a list of items to analyze, and create a thread that executes a method that checks if it contains any item in the list and run the normal process

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use multithreading, or maybe some async/await operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: At a high level my program is reading serial data (main window), displaying serial data (main window), and analyzing the data (pop-up window). Everything is sequential since I need to receive a line of data and immediately analyze it. Would multithreading run these in parallel? If so I am not sure that would work since I need the sequential order

Comment: Yeah, but maybe analyzing data after displaying is taking too long, then maybe the analyzing part you whould do it with something like a background worker or something. This way you will see the data in the screen, but you will not need to wait until the data is analyzed to, for example, close the window. ;)